# Can Linux play HDMI 1.4a 3D stereoscopic content?

Tags: linux, nvidia-graphics-card, blu-ray, 3d

I'm aware that there are no Bluray players for Linux but I'm wondering if it's possible to play Full 3D HD (1080p, Side-By-Side) MKV files (or Bluray BDMV folders, etc).

Full 3D HD files are actually two 1080p frames "side-by-side" so the effective resolution is 3840x1200.  In order to play these properly the software needs to switch to TV into 3D mode (or however HDMI 1.4a works).

I don't think simply playing the 3840x1200 resolution file will work so are there any options out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, Linux does support playback of Blu-Ray output, it's just that it's a restricted format so you have to set it up yourself. Your best bet for Blu-Ray 3d on Linux, is the proprietary [PowerDVD Ultra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerDVD). It's not free but it works with most hardware.

Comment: Is PowerDVD for Linux still available?  According to the wiki page you linked, it's not being sold any more and I'm not sure the last version ever released supported 3D?

Comment: Yeah I didn't realise 11 had come out. There always seems to be a delay in linux availability. You can still get 10 but I can't ethically give you a link even if you just wanted to use it until 11 supports linux. Of course, google doesn't share my high standards.

Comment: This is untrue, PowerDVD for Linux only ever supported playback of DVDs, not Blu-Rays.

Answer (score 1):

You can play these files with Bino 3D which is open source and free:
http://bino3d.org/download.html

It is sometimes not very good at detecting the format(often for me the left-right is reversed), but it is easy to flip it to the correct format and swap eyes.